# Python "here, . . . where" construction

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, pybrain

This is an excerpt from PyBrain's website. I get most of what is going on, but one line has me completely stumped. I've never seen anything like this in python code before. Here is the whole loop, for context:

```
    for c in [0, 1, 2]:
        #have no friggin idea how this next line works
        here, _ = where(tstdata['class']==c)
        plot(tstdata['input'][here, 0], tstdata['input'][here, 1], 'o')
```

the weird "where" qualifier is from NumPy, and I get what that's doing. I've never seen "here" used that way though. Can someone explain exactly what this is doing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nothing magic, `where` is a simple function, defined somewhere else, which returns a tuple of two elements, and assign action auto unpacks them to `here` variable, and `_` variable. If instead of function `where` we try with simple `tuple`:

```
>>> here, _ = ("a", "b")
>>> here
'a'
>>> _
'b'
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems like a weird way to unpack a tuple to me. Why assign to a lonely underscore? Is this a standard python idiom for unpacking?

Comment: Underscore, I think, is becoming a convention for a variable name, which we are not intending to use. However, it can be used if needed.

Answer (score 1):

`pybrain` is using the result to slice a multidimensional array.

```
>>> a
array([[3, 1, 0, 2],
       [1, 2, 1, 2],
       [1, 3, 3, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0]])

>>> b
array([3, 3, 1, 2])

>>> np.where(b==3)
(array([0, 1]),)
```

Using this naively will either return a higher dimensional array or do wonky things:

```
>>> a[np.where(b==3),0]
array([[3, 1]])
```

You can either unpack the tuple or do below to return the expected result:

```
>>> a[np.where(b==3)[0],0]
array([3, 1])
```

The reason this is dangerous:

```
>>> here, _ = np.where(b==3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

To change the above:

```
here= where(tstdata['class']==c)
plot(tstdata['input'][here[0], 0], tstdata['input'][here[0], 1], 'o')
```

Comment: The OP said he understands `where`. He doesn't understand `tuple` unpacking.

Comment: The `tuple` unpacking as shown isnt always syntactically valid. A full explanation of whats going on should alleviate that.

Comment: @Ophion, can you elaborate on that? What is a better syntax?

Comment: @AndrewMartin If `a` is a 1D array using `here, _ = np.where(a==x)` will return an error, its better to use the general case and slice the tuple as `np.where(a==x)[0]`, which will always work.